# Excel Dynamic Rows sums

Tags: excel, sum, conditional-statements

I'm not sure if this is the best way to describe this, but here goes. I have data in the form of:

```
Name   Line-Number Cost

Name1   1           $3
Name1   2           $4
Name1   3           $5
Name2   1           $10
Name2   2           $20
Name2   3           $15
Name2   4           $5
```

I'd like to arrive at:

```
Name  Line-Number Cost  TotalCost

Name1      1       $3     $12
Name1      2       $4     $0
Name1      3       $5     $0
Name2      1       $10    $50
Name2      2       $20    $0
Name2      3       $15    $0
Name2      4       $5     $0
```

Essentially I want "subtotals" as a new column on the first line of each individual. There are enough names that I cannot do this manually and a wide variety of numbers per person.

Is this possible? Thank you!

Comment: I am embarrassed to note that I attempted to edit this but cannot get it to show 3 items per line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
=IF(A2<>A1,SUMIF(A:A,A2,C:C),0)
```

in D2 and copy down.

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula:

```
=IF(A2<>A1,SUMIF(A:A,A2,C:C),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't this what I did?

Comment: Sorry, may be you and me trying to answer same time. Thats why I could not notice your answer.